# Is there a way to return POSIXct object to R from C?

Tags: c++, c, r

I want to create a vector of datetime object in C/C++ and then return them to R. In the documentation of POSIXct class it is written that it keeps seconds since 1970-01-01 as a vector of numeric values, so I guess there should be a way to do the conversion from double to POSIXct in C.

I have this C code and want to return POSIXct dates instead of REAL numbers.

```
SEXP func()
{
    SEXP dates;
    PROTECT(dates = allocVector(REALSXP, 2));
    REAL(dates)[0] = 1402329599.12456;
    REAL(dates)[1] = 1402329600.85404;
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: C/C++? I don't know any programming language like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy as [setting the class](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Classes).

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

SEXP func()
{
    SEXP dates, class;
    PROTECT(dates = allocVector(REALSXP, 2));
    REAL(dates)[0] = 1402329599.12456;
    REAL(dates)[1] = 1402329600.85404;

    class = PROTECT(allocVector(STRSXP, 2));
    SET_STRING_ELT(class, 0, mkChar("POSIXct"));
    SET_STRING_ELT(class, 1, mkChar("POSIXt"));
    classgets(dates, class);

    UNPROTECT(2);
    return dates;
}
```

You might also want to set the `tzone` attribute.

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

SEXP func()
{
    SEXP dates, class, tz_attr;
    PROTECT(dates = allocVector(REALSXP, 2));
    REAL(dates)[0] = 1402329599.12456;
    REAL(dates)[1] = 1402329600.85404;

    class = PROTECT(allocVector(STRSXP, 2));
    SET_STRING_ELT(class, 0, mkChar("POSIXct"));
    SET_STRING_ELT(class, 1, mkChar("POSIXt"));
    classgets(dates, class);

    tz_attr = PROTECT(allocVector(STRSXP, 1));
    SET_STRING_ELT(tz_attr, 0, mkChar("GMT"));
    setAttrib(dates, install("tzone"), tz_attr);

    UNPROTECT(3);
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: Sorry one more question. Can you let me know how to set timezone? This one does not work.

    `SEXP tz_attr = PROTECT(allocVector(STRSXP, 2));`
    `SET_STRING_ELT(tz_attr, 0, mkChar("GMT"));`
    `SET_STRING_ELT(tz_attr, 1, mkChar("CET"));`
    `setAttrib(dates, mkChar("tzone"), tz_attr);`

Comment: @SamvelHovsepyan: You shouldn't try to set the `tzone` attribute to more than one timezone.  `"CET"` is probably not a valid timezone (see `?timezone`). `setAttrib(dates, mkChar("tzone"), tz_attr);` is not how the docs show you to set attributes (you need `install("tzone")`, not `mkChar("tzone")`).

Comment: When I do this `setAttrib(dates, install("tzone"), tz_attr);` I get the following error message **Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : invalid 'tz' value**. But when I set attribute to `class` timezone stays as previous: like this `setAttrib(class, install("tzone"), tz_attr);`

Comment: @SamvelHovsepyan: Are you sure you're following the instructions exactly? Your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24144072/271616) didn't follow the example in my answer, and I wouldn't expect it to work because you didn't set the class correctly.

Comment: It is working ok. The problem is that it is alwasy shows the same timezone `MSK`. Can you let me know how to set `tzone` attribute from C code to `POSIXct` object? What should be added to you answer. It will be fantastic if you edit your answer so it also sets `tzone` to `GMT` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the coercion from R:

```
r_func <- function( tz=NULL) .POSIXct(.Call("func"), tz)
```